# If my sheet has invalid data trigger dialog box

Tags: excel, validation, vba

I used macro recorder to discover ActiveSheet.CircleInvalid which circles any data that doesn't meet the cells data validation criteria. I linked the macro to a form control; So far I have:

```
Sub datavalidationcheck()
 ActiveSheet.CircleInvalid
 '//Add  if there are invalid cells being circled then prompt user with dialog box 
  '//else 
 Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show
End Sub
```

I am hoping to find out how to make a dialog box appear that requests the user fix the invalid data. The commented out stuff is the pseudocode for what I am trying to accomplish.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an idea, which is based on the fact that the circles around invalid data are actual shapes on the worksheet:

```
Sub Invalid()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim ShapesBefore As Long
Dim ShapesAfter As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set cell = ActiveCell
    With ws
        .ClearCircles
        ShapesBefore = ws.Shapes.Count
        .CircleInvalid
        ShapesAfter = ws.Shapes.Count
        If ShapesAfter > ShapesBefore Then
            MsgBox "Invalid Circles displayed"
        End If
    End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, I added the functionality to save and send as email through outlook. with this code :
       If ShapesAfter = ShapesBefore Then
       Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show
        End If
Is there a way to populate the e-mail fields (to: subject: and body:) and automatically send it?

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! Good question, I learned something new. I suggest researching your email question - there's lots of info out there - and coming back here and asking a separate question if needed.